# In how much danger were the students who were evacuated for the battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Before the battle of Hogwarts, many students were evacuated from the building.  All underage students had to leave, and some students of age have left as well.  These students were taken through the secret tunnel from the Room of Requirement to the Hog's Head pub, and Apparated away from there.  The group was led by Madam Pomfrey, Mr. Filch, and prefects.

In chapter 30 of *Hallows*, Harry argues that

> ‘if Voldemort and the Death Eaters are concentrating on the school boundaries they won't be interested in anyone who's Disapparating out of the Hog's Head.’

and Professor McGonagall agrees.

After the students are led away, we hear very little about them in the novel.  We know that Madame Pomfrey returns to the building, from which I think the Disapparition went without problems, and we learn that Colin Creevey sneaked back, probably even before he got Disapparated.

My question is, to where were all the evacuated the students Disapparated, and how safe they were during and shortly after the battle?  Even if the Death Eaters are concentrating on Hogwarts, there could be some snatchers and other supporters of the Dark Lord out there hunting.  During the battle, the army of the Dark Lord would probably notice how few students remained in the building, and might have the idea to leave and hunt them.  They could try to capture the young students to use them as hostages to bargain with Hogwarts, thus gaining bargaining chips for the battle itself.

I'm worried about these students, so please tell me why I could know they were safe.

Comment: Somewhere else I've read on this site that Voldemort's goal definitely wasn't to exterminate the students, so I'd say they were basically safe.

Comment: @Lohoris: sure, Neville Longbottom says so in chapter 29: ‘They don't want to spill too much pure blood, so they'll torture us a bit if we're mouthy but they won't actually kill us.’  However, he continues to explain that ‘The only people in real danger are the ones whose friends and relatives on the outside are giving trouble. They get taken hostage. […]’

Comment: over-analysis much? If something, either way, did happen to them, it would have been significant enough to be included in the books/movies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're suggesting scenarios that canon has already told us didn't happen, so I don't think you need to worry about Voldemort's army leaving Hogwarts to search for missing students or to try and capture them and hold them hostage. *Deathly Hallows* clarifies neither of these things took place on the night of the Battle of Hogwarts. Voldemort was hunting *Harry* -- at that point, he wouldn't have cared about capturing any other student.

Canon doesn't say to where the evacuating students Disapparated to. I would imagine they went to their homes, but this is only a guess, and any other ideas would be pure conjecture as well.

The students were basically safe. *Deathly Hallows* suggests all the evacuating underage students successfully made it through the tunnel from Hogwarts to the Hog's Head, and Disapparated from there. Aberforth was able to close down the Hog's Head once the last student had gone. As well, Voldemort and his army's focus was on destroying Harry and Hogwarts and wasn't concerned with tracking down students who had left -- *Deathly Hallows* confirms this. Aberforth actually suggested to Harry that the Order be the one to take hostages -- he suggested they should have held back some Slytherin students who were the children of Death Eaters, but Harry dismissed this idea as unnecessary (because Voldemort wouldn't care about preserving their safety).

As to Snatchers and other Voldemort supporters being around Hogwarts or Hogsmeade hunting down escaping students, it's possible, but, again, conjecture because canon doesn't address it.

You can know these students are safe because *Deathly Hallows* verifies that they made it out of Hogwarts and Apparated away from Hogsmeade. The only underage student documented as having returned to Hogwarts to fight, and subsequently being killed, is Colin Creevey.

Comment: I don't see why Apparating away from Hogsmeade would guarantee their safety.  Whether they go to their parents' house or in a remote forest, evil wizards may find them there, because Hogwarts' enchantments no longer protect them.

Comment: @b_jonas - it's dangerous to walk down the street. A brick may fall on your head. The question is what's MORE dangerous and by how much.

Comment: Why do you think that Hogwarts is the only place where protective enchantments apply? The students could have Apparated to other protected places. But, again, I think you've asked a question that cannot be given a canon-based, definitive answer. In this question you yourself provide a direct quote regarding the students' safety that *suggests* they would be fine if they were to evacuate Hogwarts. I'm not sure why you're arguing about it. RE: my typo, I prefer to just quietly go in and make a fix. Your comment seemed kind of petty; this is a collaborative site after all. I was surprised. :/

Answer (score 1):

Voldemort, and the Death Eaters don't attack students, unless, the students are specifically attacking them first. Voldemort makes it very clear that he is interested in schooling, and that the teachers, the school, and the students are important to him. In the battle of Hogwarts the only reason students and teachers are fighting and in danger, are because they choose to stay and fight instead of simply walking away.

Its also important to mention all current students are AT LEAST half bloods, as all of the muggle born students were already kicked out of the school.

> ‘I know that you are preparing to fight.’ There were screams
>   amongst the students, some of whom clutched each other, looking 
>   around in terror for the source of the sound. ‘Your efforts are
>   futile. You cannot fight me. I do not want to kill you. I have great
>   respect for the teachers of Hogwarts. I do not want to spill magical
>   blood.’

So only students or students of parents directly involved in the battle of Hogwarts are threatened, people who are actively fighting against Voldemort.